# Read values of the loss function in Tensorflow 2.3.1

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow, customization, loss-function

I am aiming to make a personal loss function, and for that i would like to access the values which I receive through parameters. The goal is to just has these values received in *y_true* in some np array, make some modifications on it, and then to operate the loss function in fact. I have tried to convert the data from *Tensor* to *np.array*, using the *Tensor.numpy()*, but the result is:

**AttributeError: 'Tensor' object has no attribute 'numpy'**

Indeed, this error seems to be related to the fact that my variable *y_true* is not a *EagerTensor*, but just *Tensor*. Since I am trying to personalize my layer and model creation, I dont know how to enable the *Eager Execution Mode*. Here is the code I am writing:

```
import os

os.environ["TF_CPP_MIN_LOG_LEVEL"] = "2"
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import keras
from tensorflow.keras import layers
from tensorflow.keras.datasets import mnist
import numpy as np

(x_train, y_train), (x_test, y_test) = mnist.load_data()
x_train = x_train.reshape(-1, 28 * 28).astype("float32") / 255.0
x_test = x_test.reshape(-1, 28 * 28).astype("float32") / 255.0


class Dense(layers.Layer):
    def __init__(self, units):
        super(Dense, self).__init__()
        self.units = units

    def build(self, input_shape):
        self.w = self.add_weight(
            name="w",
            shape=(input_shape[-1], self.units),
            initializer="random_normal",
            trainable=True, # We can define whether a variable will be trained in the backpropagation 
                            # Process or not, by changing the field 'trainable'. 
        )
        self.b = self.add_weight(
            name="b", shape=(self.units,), initializer="random_normal", trainable=True,
        )

    def call(self, inputs):
        return tf.matmul(inputs, self.w) + self.b # Defining the operation of the layer, i.e. the forward
                                                  # propagation methodology


class MyReLU(layers.Layer):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MyReLU, self).__init__()

    def call(self, x):
        return tf.math.maximum(x, 0)


class MyModel(keras.Model):  # model.fit, model.evalute, model.predict
    def __init__(self, num_classes=10):
        super(MyModel, self).__init__()
        self.dense1 = Dense(64)
        self.dense2 = Dense(num_classes)
        self.relu = MyReLU()

    def call(self, x):
        x = self.dense1(x) # Creating the first layer and initializing it

        x = self.relu(x)   # Genereting the output of the first layer through a personalized
                           # ReLu activation function

        x = self.dense2(x) # This output is passed as input to the next (and in this case final) layer

        return x

def Personalized_loss_procedure(y_true, y_pred):

    array = y_true.numpy()

    y_true = tf.cast(y_true, tf.float32)
    subtrac = tf.subtract(y_true, y_pred)
    powl = tf.pow(subtrac, tf.constant(2.0, dtype=tf.float32))
    divide = tf.reduce_sum(powl)
    sqrt = tf.divide(divide, tf.cast(tf.size(y_true), tf.float32))
    return tf.sqrt(sqrt)

model = MyModel()
model.compile(
    loss=Personalized_loss_procedure,
    optimizer=keras.optimizers.Adam(),
    metrics=["accuracy"],
)
 
model.fit(x_train, y_train, batch_size=32, epochs=2, verbose=2)
model.evaluate(x_test, y_test, batch_size=32, verbose=2)
```

In this situation, how can I convert from *Tensor* to *Numpy*? Is there some way to convert from *Tensor* to *EagerTensor* in this case?
I am using Tensorflow 2.3.1, but would not be a problem to regress to older versions of tf2.
In the code posted, the line in interest is that one righ bellow the statement of *def Personalized_loss_procedure*.

Answer (score 0):

You can not use numpy in loss function because tensorflow will notbe able to propagate errors.